# How do I write XML files directly to a zip archive?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, zip

What is the proper way to write a list of XML files using JAXB directly to a zip archive without using a 3rd party library.

Would it be better to just write all the XML files to a directory and then zip?

Comment: Why would you write an XML file using JAXB? Why wouldn't you copy it to the zip directly

Comment: The zip is more to archive everything rather than compress it. Though its the editor that really handles the files i needed a solution which allowed me to alter the files outside of the editor for quick alterations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others pointed out, you can use the `ZipOutputStream` class to create a ZIP-file. The trick to put multiple files in a single ZIP-file is to use the `ZipEntry` descriptors prior to writing (marshalling) the JAXB XML data in the `ZipOutputStream`. So your code might look similar to this one:

```
JAXBElement jaxbElement1 = objectFactory.createRoot(rootType);
JAXBElement jaxbElement2 = objectFactory.createRoot(rootType);

ZipOutputStream zos = null; 
try {
  zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("xml-file.zip"));
  // add zip-entry descriptor
  ZipEntry ze1 = new ZipEntry("xml-file-1.xml");
  zos.putNextEntry(ze1);
  // add zip-entry data
  marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement1, zos);
  ZipEntry ze2 = new ZipEntry("xml-file-2.xml");
  zos.putNextEntry(ze2);
  marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement2, zos);
  zos.flush();
} finally {
  if (zos != null) {
    zos.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The "proper" way — without using a 3rd party library — would be to use [`java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html).

Personally, though, I prefer [TrueZip](http://truezip.java.net/).

> TrueZIP is a Java based plug-in framework for virtual file systems (VFS) which provides transparent access to archive files as if they were just plain directories.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what JAXB has to do with anything, nor XML - file contents are file contents.   Your question is really "How can I output characters directly to a zip archive"

To do that, open a [ZipOututStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) and use the API to create entries then write contents to each entry. Remember that a zip archive is like a series of named files within the archive.

btw, `ZipOututStream` is part of the JDK (ie it's not a "library")